# Tkinter LabelFrame not expanding in both directions when using grid()

Tags: python, tkinter, ttk

So I'm trying to expand my LabelFrame named "Admin Frame" in the X and Y directions somewhat like the `pack()` system's `fill=BOTH` argument but it doesn't seem to be working. But I want to be able to do this with the `grid()`system because I have a complex interface.

[image: How the LabelFrame looks like]

This is my code for the LabelFrame:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk


root = Tk()
root.title("Election App Mockup")
root.geometry("800x600")
root.resizable(0,0)

frameStyle = ttk.Style().configure("my.TLabelframe.Label")

adminFrame = ttk.LabelFrame(root, text="Admin Panel", style="my.TLabelframe")
adminWinLabel = ttk.Label(adminFrame, text="Welcome Admin")
voterOpBtn = ttk.Button(adminFrame, text="Configure Voters' List", style="my.TButton")
candidateOpBtn = ttk.Button(adminFrame, text="Configure Candidates' List", style="my.TButton")
setVoteSessionBtn = ttk.Button(adminFrame, text="Setup Voting Session", style="my.TButton")
startVoterSessionBtn = ttk.Button(adminFrame, text="Start a Voting Session", style="my.TButton", padding=(25,3,25,3))
adminSettingBtn = ttk.Button(adminFrame, text="Admin Settings", style="my.TButton", )
adminLogoutBtn = ttk.Button(adminFrame, text="Logout", style="my.TButton", padding=(20,3,20,3))

adminWinLabel.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=2, pady=(170,5), padx=(150,0))
voterOpBtn.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=(150,5), pady=(10,10), ipadx=15)
candidateOpBtn.grid(row=1, column=1, padx=(10,5), pady=(10,10))
setVoteSessionBtn.grid(row=2, column=0, padx=(150,5), pady=(10,10), ipadx=15)
startVoterSessionBtn.grid(row=2, column=1, padx=(10,5), pady=(10,10))
adminSettingBtn.grid(row=3, column=0, padx=(130,0), pady=(10,10), columnspan=2)
adminLogoutBtn.grid(row=4, column=0, padx=(130,0), pady=(10,10), columnspan=2)

adminFrame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=NSEW)
adminFrame.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
adminFrame.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

root.mainloop()
```

I've tried adding extra arguments like `ipadx` and `ipady` in but it doesn't work:

```
adminFrame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=NSEW, ipadx=200, ipady=20)
```

Adding a `padding` argument in the adminFrame does work but it is very tricky to work with just to expand the frame to the window's full length and breadth.

Thanks in advance! Oh and do note that I did not learn object oriented programming in python, so I won't understand any answers using the class system.

Comment: What did you on `adminFrame`'s children? `.pack(...)` or `.grid(...)`?

Comment: Please show a complete [mcve].

Comment: `adminWinLabel.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=2, pady=(170,5), padx=(150,0))`
`voterOpBtn.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=(150,5), pady=(10,10), ipadx=15)`
`candidateOpBtn.grid(row=1, column=1, padx=(10,5), pady=(10,10))`
`setVoteSessionBtn.grid(row=2, column=0, padx=(150,5), pady=(10,10), ipadx=15)`
`startVoterSessionBtn.grid(row=2, column=1, padx=(10,5), pady=(10,10))`
`adminSettingBtn.grid(row=3, column=0, padx=(130,0), pady=(10,10), columnspan=2)`
`adminLogoutBtn.grid(row=4, column=0, padx=(130,0), pady=(10,10), columnspan=2)`

These go in the adminFrame

Comment: Try adding `adminFrame.grid_propagate(False)`.

Comment: Ok I'll try doing that. Thanks

Comment: Nope, adding `adminFrame.grid_propagate(False)` didn't work. Instead the whole Frame disappears

Comment: @BryanOakley I hope my question is more legible now. If not, please tell me

Answer (score 1):

> So I'm trying to expand my LabelFrame named "Admin Frame" in the X and Y directions somewhat like the pack() system's fill=BOTH argument but it doesn't seem to be working.

As a rule of thumb, any time you use `grid` to manage widgets, you should give at least one row and one column a weight greater than zero. You are putting `adminFrame` in the root window with `grid`, but you haven't given any rows or columns in the root window a weight.

So, if you want `adminFrame` to expand to fill the window, you need to give a weight of 1 to row 0 and column 0. The other thing that needs to be done -- that you are already doing -- is to set the `sticky` attribute so that the frame "sticks" to all four sides of the space allocated to it.

```
adminFrame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=NSEW)
root.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
root.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
```

[image: screenshot showing the frame filling the window]

Comment: That works but the frame still doesn't cover the entire area as shown in the image

https://imgur.com/ZlKjbkn

Comment: @LightningFryer It works for me. I added those two lines to your code and the labelframe clearly fills the window.

Comment: @LightningFryer When using this approach are you sure you weren't missing the `sticky` parameter to `adminFrame.grid()`?

Comment: @LightningFryer I agree with TheLizzard: from your screenshot it looks like you haven't used the `sticky` attribute properly. Either that, or the code you're running isn't the same as the code in your question.

Comment: Perhaps there is something wrong with the frame when it is referenced elsewhere. I do have 2 functions which do `grid_forget()` and `grid()` to hide and show the frames. Perhaps I could link you my repository? Because this project is awfully long and the complete codebase is there in my repo.

Comment: This answer still applies to your whole code: anywhere you're using `grid` to manage child widgets, you need to give at least one row and one column a weight. Personally, I recommend using `pack` when you only have one widget inside a parent. It's much easier since you don't have to remember to configure weights.

Comment: @TheLizzard Yep it seems like the missing `sticky` argument was the issue, I had used `pack()` for the `adminFrame` and forgot to switch back to `grid()`. Now it works

Answer (score 0):

Look at this:

```py
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk


root = Tk()
root.title("Election App Mockup")
root.geometry("800x600")
# root.resizable(False, False)

frameStyle = ttk.Style().configure("my.TLabelframe.Label")

adminFrame = ttk.LabelFrame(root, text="Admin Panel", style="my.TLabelframe")

adminWinLabel = ttk.Label(adminFrame, text="Welcome Admin")

# A frame for the centre 4 buttons
centre_buttons_frame = Frame(adminFrame)

voterOpBtn = ttk.Button(centre_buttons_frame, text="Configure Voters' List", style="my.TButton")
candidateOpBtn = ttk.Button(centre_buttons_frame, text="Configure Candidates' List", style="my.TButton")
setVoteSessionBtn = ttk.Button(centre_buttons_frame, text="Setup Voting Session", style="my.TButton")
startVoterSessionBtn = ttk.Button(centre_buttons_frame, text="Start a Voting Session", style="my.TButton", padding=(25,3,25,3))
adminSettingBtn = ttk.Button(adminFrame, text="Admin Settings", style="my.TButton", )
adminLogoutBtn = ttk.Button(adminFrame, text="Logout", style="my.TButton", padding=(20,3,20,3))

# I think the buttons looks better when they have an equal size so I added
#   sticky="ew" to expand them in the horizontal direction.
voterOpBtn.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="ew", padx=(0,15), pady=10, ipadx=15)
candidateOpBtn.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky="ew", padx=(15,0), pady=10)
setVoteSessionBtn.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky="ew", padx=(0,15), pady=10, ipadx=15)
startVoterSessionBtn.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky="ew", padx=(15,0), pady=10)

adminWinLabel.grid(row=1, column=1, pady=(0,5))
centre_buttons_frame.grid(row=2, column=1)
adminSettingBtn.grid(row=3, column=1, pady=10)
adminLogoutBtn.grid(row=4, column=1, pady=(10,0))

# `adminFrame` is packed in the root so it can expand. There should be a way
#   to make it work with .grid, but .pack is easier in this case
adminFrame.pack(fill="both", expand=True)
# Expand the 0th and 6th row - there are no widgets
adminFrame.grid_rowconfigure((0, 6), weight=1)
adminFrame.grid_columnconfigure((0, 3), weight=1)

root.mainloop()
```

It looks like this on my computer:
[image]

I added a frame for the centre 4 buttons so that I can avoid `columnspan`. Also I used `adminFrame.pack(fill="both", expand=True)` because it is easier than using `.grid_propagate(False)` and manually setting the width and height of the frame.

Right now, the GUI should look good with any window size.

Comment: Thanks, this works. I'll use `pack()` for my LabelFrames for this project because on second thought it does make more sense. But could you please show how you would do it using `grid()` as well? It might come handy for me in the future